# how can I make button align with my images

Tags: css

I want to make this kind of look good and I'm trying things out with sliders using JavaScript.
My buttons stay on both sides of my images but not at the center, they are at the bottom. How can I make them be side by side?

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body{
    background-color: #FFFC35;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#slider{
    height: 100%;
}

.btn{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background:  #4b5052;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="prev()" class="btn"> Prev </button>
    <img id="slider" src="1.jpg" width="200px" height="100px"/>
    <button onclick="next()" class="btn"> Next </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `display: table-cell;` like this.
Especially on the `body`. For something like this you should take a look at "Flexbox".
With `display: flex;` you can easily center elements.

Take a look at this example:

```css
body{
    background-color: #FFFC35;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#slider{
    height: 100%;
}

.btn{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background:  #4b5052;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
      <button onclick="prev()" class="btn"> Prev </button>
      <img id="slider" src="https://placehold.it/500" width="200px" height="100px"/>
      <button onclick="next()" class="btn"> Next </button>
  </div>
</div>
```